# How to make a picture shadow with CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes, shadowbox

I want to implement a picture shadow as below

[image: picture shadow]

I tried to use the following code, but that can't work as I want

**Code snippet:**

```css
.oval {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #1abc9c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 100px 4px -2px rgba(15, 13, 13, 0.53);
  box-shadow: 0 100px 4px -2px rgba(15, 13, 13, 0.53);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(5);
  transform: scaleX(5);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

I want to put the HTML code below the picture if the CSS code works well.

Comment: can you post a html code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method to achieve this would be to make use of a pseudo-element with CSS transform. In the below snippet, the `:after` pseudo-element is rotated in X-axis by close to `90deg` (but not by equal to `90deg`) to give it an oval like appearance. Then by adding a `radial-gradient` background and `box-shadow`, we can get an appearance close to the image in the picture.

One advantage of this approach is that the shadow that is produced is responsive and so it can adapt to change in container/image sizes.

```css
.oval{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 8px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.oval img{
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.oval:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 40px); /* to offset for the shadow */
  top: 25%;
  left: 20px; /* to offset for the shadow spread */
  border-radius: 50%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-origin: 50% bottom;
  transform: rotateX(85deg);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(216,216,216, 0.5), rgba(248,248,248,0.1));
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 20px rgba(248,248,248,0.5);
}

/* Just for demo */

.oval#oval2{ height: 300px; width: 300px; }
div{ float: left; }
```

```html
<div class="oval">
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1' />
</div>

<div class="oval" id="oval2">
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/1' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this quite easily if you're able to wrap the `<img />` element in a container tag such as a `<div>`. By using the `:after` pseudo-selector on the parent `div`, you can achieve a similar approach using `box-shadow`.

For example, assuming you have the following markup:

You may add the following CSS definitions:

```
.image-round {
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.image-shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
  .image-shadow:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    height: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #ccc;
  }
```

Of course, you can modify the `left` and `right` properties of the `:after` pseudo-element to achieve a better look.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ohavm3vu/)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I adjust the code to implement the same as shadow shape in my picture?

Comment: As I've said, by modifying the `left`, `right` and `box-shadow` properties.

Comment: I tried a lot properties(http://jsfiddle.net/kdhva29n/), but the result always has a small different with the design picture. I think I need to drop `css` way.